# Applying angular ng-repeat on <td> instead of <tr>?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Consider the data format as

```
{
  users:        [....]

  userPropNames:        [...]

  showingAllUsers   :   false

  usersPresent  :   true
}
```

I am building the HTML table as per following rule
- Row will be defined based on `userProperNames`
- The columns will vary based on number of `users` in the dataset

The way I started is

```
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="key in queryResults.userPropNames">
          <td>checkbox</td>
          <td>{{key}}</td>
          <td>{{queryResults.users[1].properties[key]}}</td>
          <td>{{queryResults.users[2].properties[key]}}</td>
          <td>{{queryResults.users[3].properties[key]}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

and it displays the table correctly with three additional column for users.

Now I though to iterate over the users in `<td>` and create as many columns as users.

so I did

```
       <tr ng-repeat="key in queryResults.userPropNames">
          <td>checkbox</td>
          <td>{{key}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="user in queryResult.users">
            {{user.properties[key]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Now I do not see any user column data

What's incorrect with this approach?

Comment: Typo... queryResult`s` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
<td ng-repeat="user in queryResult.users">
```

Should be:

```
<td ng-repeat="user in queryResults.users">
```

Comment: Sometimes all you need is another set of eyes! :)